# Languages to develop applications for Xbox 360 kinect

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, gesture-recognition, xbox360

I know this sounds stupid and I'm propably very late to the party but here's the thing I want to program an gesture recogniction application (in the likes of this [Hand detection](https://www.morethantechnical.com/2013/05/26/extending-the-hand-tracker-with-snakes-and-optimizations-w-code-opencv/) or this [actual finger detection](https://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/12/28/hand-gesture-recognition-via-model-fitting-in-energy-minimization-wopencv/))  for the Xbox 360 Kinect. SDK (version 1.8) is found, installed and works, preliminary research is done - I only forgot to look in which language to write the code. The link from the SDK to the documentation would be the first thing to do but is a dead end, unfortunately.
From the provided examples it seems either to be C++ or C# although some old posts also claim Java. My question is: Is there a documentation not tied to the SDK and which pitfall are there in regard to developing in this specific case under C++/C#/Java? A [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/311161/Getting-most-of-Kinect-SDK-in-Csharp-part-2-of-Ima) from 2011 barely covers the beginning.

Addendum: On further looking I was prompted for the Samples site from the developer toolkit - which can be reached, yet all listed and linked examples are dead ends too.

Addendum: For reference I userd this [instruction](https://yannickloriot.com/2011/03/kinect-how-to-install-and-use-openni-on-windows-part-1/) - ultimately proving futile.

Found an version of NiTE [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3e4_6C5_YOjOGIySEluYkNibEE/edit)

Comment: It's not stupid at all...just completely off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559220/requirements-for-kinect-programming/9559472#9559472) in the past.

Personally I've used the Xbox360 sensor with OpenNI the most (because it's cross platform). Also the NITE middleware on alongside OpenNI provides some basic hand detection and even gesture detection (swipes, circle gesture, "button" push, etc.).

While OpenNI is opensource, NITE isn't so you'd be limited to what they provide.

The links you've shared use OpenCV. You can install OpenNI and compile OpenCV from source with OpenNI support. Alternatively, you can manually wrap the OpenNI frame data into an OpenCV `cv::Mat` and carry on with the OpenCV operations from there.

Here's a basic example that uses OpenNI to get the depth data and passes that to OpenCV:

```
#include <OpenNI.h>

#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // setup OpenNI
    openni::Status rc = openni::STATUS_OK;
    openni::Device device;
    openni::VideoStream depth, color;
    const char* deviceURI = openni::ANY_DEVICE;
    rc = openni::OpenNI::initialize();

    printf("After initialization:\n%s\n", openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
    rc = device.open(deviceURI);
    if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK)
    {
        printf("Device open failed:\n%s\n", openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
        openni::OpenNI::shutdown();
        return 1;
    }

    rc = depth.create(device, openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
    if (rc == openni::STATUS_OK)
    {
        rc = depth.start();
        if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK)
        {
            printf("Couldn't start depth stream:\n%s\n", openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
            depth.destroy();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't find depth stream:\n%s\n", openni::OpenNI::getExtendedError());
    }

    if (!depth.isValid())
    {
        printf("No valid depth stream. Exiting\n");
        openni::OpenNI::shutdown();
        return 2;
    }

    openni::VideoMode vm = depth.getVideoMode();
    int cols, rows;
    cols = vm.getResolutionX();
    rows = vm.getResolutionY();

    openni::VideoFrameRef frame;
    depth.start();
    // main loop
    for (;;) {
        // read OpenNI frame
        depth.readFrame(&frame);
        // get depth pixel data
        openni::DepthPixel* dData = (openni::DepthPixel*)frame.getData();
        // wrap the data in an OpenCV Mat
        Mat depthMat(rows, cols, CV_16UC1, dData);
        // for visualisation only remap depth values
        Mat depthShow;
        const float scaleFactor = 0.05f;
        depthMat.convertTo(depthShow, CV_8UC1, scaleFactor);
        if(!depthShow.empty())
        {
            imshow("depth", depthShow);
        }
        
        if (waitKey(30) == 27)   break;

    }
    // OpenNI exit cleanup
    depth.stop();
    openni::OpenNI::shutdown();
}
```

One of the tutorials you've linked to (https://github.com/royshil/OpenHPE) uses `libfreenect` which is another great cross platform option to interface with the old Kinect.

FWIW, Kinect for XBox One has better depth data, deals better with direct sunlight and the SDK has support for custom gesture recognition (see [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sunx0578/gesture-commands-with-kinect-gesture-recognition-143a605150e6) for example).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I seem to be stuck with the Windows SDK - PrimeSense having provided OpenNi and NiTE was bought by Apple and ceased operations. There is a successor OpenNI2 which wont interact with some additonal drivers. But I reckon that compiling OpenCV will work nontheless - may I can get that to work. Is that possible with the Windows SDK too?

Comment: Yes, Apple bought PrimeSense, however you can still [download OpenNI](https://structure.io/openni). You're right, OpenNI won't interact with additional drivers: LED control, accelerometer, servo motor control, audio. My assumption is the depth stream is the most important functionality and hopefully not the audio/led/motor control. Additionally, as mentioned above, the OpenHPE repo you've linked to in your question uses [libfreenect](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect) which provides access to LED/motor/accelerometer/audio...

Comment: @Quamatoc ...that being said, yes it should be possible to copy depth data from the Windows SDK into a `cv::Mat`. Doing a quick search [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876366/how-to-take-kinect-video-image-and-depth-image-with-opencv-c) popped up. It's using the older OpenCV C API (using `IplImage` instead of `cv::Mat`), however, the more important part is how to acess depth data from the Kinect SDK. You should be able to easily wrap the bytes into a `cv::Mat` (with the right dimensions, number of channels and data type)